# stderr to file; but without buffering

Tags: linux, file, redirect, stderr

I am trying to isolate a nasty bug, which brings down my linux kernel. I am printing messages to stderr and stderr is redirected to a log file. Is there a way to disable buffering on the file access? When kernel hangs, I am losing the messages in the buffer.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, `stderr` is unbuffered by default but I think that's only in terms of the C runtime. We've solved this before with:

```
fflush (stderr); fsync (fileno (stderr));
```

(although we actually did it to `stdout` but the same rules apply - the actual `fflush` may not be necessary for `stderr` but it does no harm).

The `fflush` flushes the C runtime buffers to the OS, the `fsync` forces write to disk.

Keep in mind this may severely affect your performance.

Answer (score 0):

You can force flushing the buffer, using `fflush(stderr);`

Comment: There are way to many files/libraries to enforce fflush. Also is not stderr already non-buffered? I thought the only issue was the file buffer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `setvbuf` when starting your app

```
setvbuf(stderr, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
```

However, you will get read of the stdio buffer, but still have the "in kernel" buffer problem, that won't disappear unless you fsync. However may be tracking a kernel bug from userspace isn't the best way to go at it.

Can you use a serial console and get the output on another machine ? This way you could get both the oops and the stderr messages